# WebStorm - Debuggin node.js app in Docker opens the file in the container instead of the original source

Tags: node.js, docker, webstorm

I have several repositories running node.js apps in Docker containers. When I open all of them together in WebStorm and start to debug one of them (using Node.js remote debug configuration), the debugger opens the source file inside the Docker container instead of the original one. If I open the same project alone in a different instance of WebStorm the debugger stops in the original file as expected.

Any idea what can cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such issues may occur when js relative path does not match the end of the path inside the docker container... we plan to provide a possibility to set remote root option in the debug configuration (like it's done in VS Code) to handle path mappings problems, please follow [WEB-28067](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28067) for updates

Comment: So actually I can fixed it for now by changing the workdir of each container to also include the name of the repository. Thanks!